z/OS - DB2 Primary Key - Foreign Key
I have been tasked with recovering data from our DB2 Database.  The 4-person team responsible for this all retired and the powers that be never saw the need to replace them.  Lucky me.
I am NOT a DB2 admin.  I am a COBOL programmer with DB2 knowledge.
Having said that, I have been granted Admin rights to all the databases.
The task assigned to me is as follows: I need to export all DB Schema's with the Primary Key and Foreign Key and the related tables plus as much information regarding the relationships as possible.
Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?
Here is a list of the sys(Tables)...
  1_| DB2_SYSPARM                                                                                                              
  2_| JES_SYSOUT                                                                                                               
  3_| SYSAUDITPOLICIES                                                                                                         
  4_| SYSAUDITPOLICIES_H                                                                                                       
  5_| SYSAUTOALERTS                                                                                                            
  6_| SYSAUTOALERTS_OUT                                                                                                        
  7_| SYSAUTORUNS_HIST                                                                                                         
  8_| SYSAUTORUNS_HISTOU                                                                                                       
  9_| SYSAUTOTIMEWINDOWS                                                                                                       
 10_| SYSAUXRELS                                                                                                               
 11_| SYSCHECKDEP                                                                                                              
 12_| SYSCHECKS                                                                                                                
 13_| SYSCHECKS2                                                                                                               
 14_| SYSCOLAUTH                                                                                                               
 15_| SYSCOLAUTH_H                                                                                                             
 16_| SYSCOLDIST                                                                                                               
 17_| SYSCOLDIST                                                                                                               
 18_| SYSCOLDISTSTATS                                                                                                          
 19_| SYSCOLDISTSTATS                                                                                                          
 20_| SYSCOLDIST_HIST                                                                                                          
 21_| SYSCOLSTATS                                                                                                              
 22_| SYSCOLSTATS                                                                                                              
 23_| SYSCOLUMNS                                                                                                               
 24_| SYSCOLUMNS                                                                                                               
 25_| SYSCOLUMNS_HIST                                                                                                          
 26_| SYSCONSTDEP                                                                                                              
 27_| SYSCONTEXT                                                                                                               
 28_| SYSCONTEXTAUTHIDS                                                                                                        
 29_| SYSCONTEXTAUTHID_H                                                                                                       
 30_| SYSCONTEXT_H                                                                                                             
 31_| SYSCONTROLS                                                                                                              
 32_| SYSCONTROLS_DESC                                                                                                         
 33_| SYSCONTROLS_DESC_H                                                                                                       
 34_| SYSCONTROLS_H                                                                                                            
 35_| SYSCONTROLS_RTXT                                                                                                         
 36_| SYSCONTROLS_RTXT_H                                                                                                       
 37_| SYSCOPY                                                                                                                  
 38_| SYSCTXTTRUSTATTRS                                                                                                        
 39_| SYSCTXTTRUSTATTR_H                                                                                                       
 40_| SYSDATABASE                                                                                                              
 41_| SYSDATATYPES                                                                                                             
 42_| SYSDBAUTH                                                                                                                
 43_| SYSDBAUTH_H                                                                                                              
 44_| SYSDBD_DATA                                                                                                              
 45_| SYSDBRM                                                                                                                  
 46_| SYSDEPENDENCIES                                                                                                          
 47_| SYSDUMMY1                                                                                                                
 48_| SYSDUMMYA                                                                                                                
 49_| SYSDUMMYE                                                                                                                
 50_| SYSDUMMYU                                                                                                                
 51_| SYSDYNQRY                                                                                                                
 52_| SYSDYNQRYDEP                                                                                                             
 53_| SYSDYNQRY_EXPL                                                                                                           
 54_| SYSDYNQRY_OPL                                                                                                            
 55_| SYSDYNQRY_SHTEL                                                                                                          
 56_| SYSDYNQRY_SPAL                                                                                                           
 57_| SYSDYNQRY_TXTL                                                                                                           
 58_| SYSENVIRONMENT                                                                                                           
 59_| SYSFIELDS                                                                                                                
 60_| SYSFOREIGNKEYS                                                                                                           
 61_| SYSINDEXCLEANUP                                                                                                          
 62_| SYSINDEXCONTROL                                                                                                          
 63_| SYSINDEXES                                                                                                               
 64_| SYSINDEXES                                                                                                               
 65_| SYSINDEXES_HIST                                                                                                          
 66_| SYSINDEXES_RTSECT                                                                                                        
 67_| SYSINDEXES_TREE                                                                                                          
 68_| SYSINDEXPART                                                                                                             
 69_| SYSINDEXPART_HIST                                                                                                        
 70_| SYSINDEXSPACESTATS                                                                                                       
 71_| SYSINDEXSTATS                                                                                                            
 72_| SYSINDEXSTATS                                                                                                            
 73_| SYSINDEXSTATS_HIST                                                                                                       
 74_| SYSIXSPACESTATS_H                                                                                                        
 75_| SYSJARCLASS_SOURCE                                                                                                       
 76_| SYSJARCONTENTS                                                                                                           
 77_| SYSJARDATA                                                                                                               
 78_| SYSJAROBJECTS                                                                                                            
 79_| SYSJAVAOPTS                                                                                                              
 80_| SYSJAVAPATHS                                                                                                             
 81_| SYSJSON_INDEX                                                                                                            
 82_| SYSKEYCOLUSE                                                                                                             
 83_| SYSKEYS                                                                                                                  
 84_| SYSKEYTARGETS                                                                                                            
 85_| SYSKEYTARGETSTATS                                                                                                        
 86_| SYSKEYTARGETS_HIST                                                                                                       
 87_| SYSKEYTGTDIST                                                                                                            
 88_| SYSKEYTGTDISTSTATS                                                                                                       
 89_| SYSKEYTGTDIST_HIST                                                                                                       
 90_| SYSLEVELUPDATES                                                                                                          
 91_| SYSLGRNX                                                                                                                 
 92_| SYSLOBSTATS                                                                                                              
 93_| SYSLOBSTATS_HIST                                                                                                         
 94_| SYSLOG                                                                                                                   
 95_| SYSOBDS                                                                                                                  
 96_| SYSOBD_AUX                                                                                                               
 97_| SYSOBJROLEDEP                                                                                                            
 98_| SYSPACKAGE                                                                                                               
 99_| SYSPACKAUTH                                                                                                              
100_| SYSPACKAUTH_H                                                                                                            
101_| SYSPACKCOPY                                                                                                              
102_| SYSPACKDEP                                                                                                               
103_| SYSPACKLIST                                                                                                              
104_| SYSPACKSTMT                                                                                                              
105_| SYSPACKSTMT_STMB                                                                                                         
106_| SYSPACKSTMT_STMT                                                                                                         
107_| SYSPARMS                                                                                                                 
108_| SYSPARM_SETTINGS                                                                                                         
109_| SYSPENDINGDDL                                                                                                            
110_| SYSPENDINGDDLTEXT                                                                                                        
111_| SYSPENDINGOBJECTS                                                                                                        
112_| SYSPKSYSTEM                                                                                                              
113_| SYSPLAN                                                                                                                  
114_| SYSPLANAUTH                                                                                                              
115_| SYSPLANAUTH_H                                                                                                            
116_| SYSPLANDEP                                                                                                               
117_| SYSPLSYSTEM                                                                                                              
118_| SYSPRINT                                                                                                                 
119_| SYSPROFILE_TEXT                                                                                                          
120_| SYSPSMOUT                                                                                                                
121_| SYSQUERY                                                                                                                 
122_| SYSQUERYOPTS                                                                                                             
123_| SYSQUERYPLAN                                                                                                             
124_| SYSQUERYPREDICATE                                                                                                        
125_| SYSQUERYSEL                                                                                                              
126_| SYSQUERY_AUX                                                                                                             
127_| SYSRELS                                                                                                                  
128_| SYSRESAUTH                                                                                                               
129_| SYSRESAUTH_H                                                                                                             
130_| SYSROLES                                                                                                                 
131_| SYSROUTINEAUTH                                                                                                           
132_| SYSROUTINEAUTH_H                                                                                                         
133_| SYSROUTINES                                                                                                              
134_| SYSROUTINESTEXT                                                                                                          
135_| SYSROUTINES_OPTS                                                                                                         
136_| SYSROUTINES_SRC                                                                                                          
137_| SYSROUTINES_TREE                                                                                                         
138_| SYSSCHEMAAUTH                                                                                                            
139_| SYSSCHEMAAUTH_H                                                                                                          
140_| SYSSEQUENCEAUTH                                                                                                          
141_| SYSSEQUENCEAUTH_H                                                                                                        
142_| SYSSEQUENCES                                                                                                             
143_| SYSSEQUENCESDEP                                                                                                          
144_| SYSSESSION                                                                                                               
145_| SYSSESSION_DATA                                                                                                          
146_| SYSSESSION_EX                                                                                                            
147_| SYSSESSION_GV                                                                                                            
148_| SYSSESSION_STATUS                                                                                                        
149_| SYSSPTSEC_DATA                                                                                                           
150_| SYSSPTSEC_EXPL                                                                                                           
151_| SYSSTATFEEDBACK                                                                                                          
152_| SYSSTMT                                                                                                                  
153_| SYSSTOGROUP                                                                                                              
154_| SYSSTRINGS                                                                                                               
155_| SYSSYNONYMS                                                                                                              
156_| SYSTABAUTH                                                                                                               
157_| SYSTABAUTH_H                                                                                                             
158_| SYSTABCONST                                                                                                              
159_| SYSTABLEPART                                                                                                             
160_| SYSTABLEPART                                                                                                             
161_| SYSTABLEPART_HIST                                                                                                        
162_| SYSTABLES                                                                                                                
163_| SYSTABLES                                                                                                                
164_| SYSTABLESPACE                                                                                                            
165_| SYSTABLESPACE                                                                                                            
166_| SYSTABLESPACESTATS                                                                                                       
167_| SYSTABLES_HIST                                                                                                           
168_| SYSTABLES_PROFILES                                                                                                       
169_| SYSTABSPACESTATS_H                                                                                                       
170_| SYSTABSTATS                                                                                                              
171_| SYSTABSTATS                                                                                                              
172_| SYSTABSTATS_HIST                                                                                                         
173_| SYSTEM_HOSTNAME                                                                                                          
174_| SYSTEXTCOLUMNS                                                                                                           
175_| SYSTEXTCONFIGURATION                                                                                                     
176_| SYSTEXTCONNECTINFO                                                                                                       
177_| SYSTEXTDEFAULTS                                                                                                          
178_| SYSTEXTINDEXES                                                                                                           
179_| SYSTEXTLOCKS                                                                                                             
180_| SYSTEXTSERVERHISTORY                                                                                                     
181_| SYSTEXTSERVERS                                                                                                           
182_| SYSTEXTSTATUS                                                                                                            
183_| SYSTLOB1                                                                                                                 
184_| SYSTRIGGERS                                                                                                              
185_| SYSTRIGGERS_STMT                                                                                                         
186_| SYSUSERAUTH                                                                                                              
187_| SYSUSERAUTH_H                                                                                                            
188_| SYSUTIL                                                                                                                  
189_| SYSUTILX                                                                                                                 
190_| SYSVARIABLEAUTH                                                                                                          
191_| SYSVARIABLES                                                                                                             
192_| SYSVARIABLES_DESC                                                                                                        
193_| SYSVARIABLES_TEXT                                                                                                        
194_| SYSVIEWDEP                                                                                                               
195_| SYSVIEWDEP_H                                                                                                             
196_| SYSVIEWS                                                                                                                 
197_| SYSVIEWS_STMT                                                                                                            
198_| SYSVIEWS_TREE                                                                                                            
199_| SYSVOLUMES                                                                                                               
200_| SYSXMLRELS                                                                                                               
201_| SYSXMLSTRINGS                                                                                                            
202_| SYSXMLTYPMOD                                                                                                             
203_| SYSXMLTYPMSCHEMA                  


Reverse-Engineering a physical-model from an existing database is a solved problem. Many tools exist, but support for Db2-for-Z/OS might be restricted (or at least, FULL support).  Modelling tools like Erwin, Embarcadero Er/Studio etc can help but are costly. Free tools (if properly configured with a correct driver ) can also help even with limitations.  IBM's own Data Studio (latest version, only when serviced with the most recent fixpack) will also help. Most likely you will need a subset of schemas grouped into subject areas, as distinct from EVERY schema together.

@mao Thank you for your time!
Cost is an issue here.  Shop is small on a leased LPAR with poor management.
Would you have any experience with SQL and DB2 administration?  Maybe you could point me in the right direction, and I can start experimenting with a few queries.

Do not re-invent a wheel, a fool's errand. Choose a free tool (e.g. IBM Data Studio serviced to current fixpacks), or many others (do your own research for rdbms-reverse-engineering physical models , free ones) , and use it wisely. Many tools exist. It's not allowed to ask for product recommendations here on stackoverflow, but you can ask elsewhere also.
